# How publish my web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have Solution with web site MyProject.
I need publish this web site. 
In popup menu I see Build Web Site and Publish Web Site

[image]

I publish my site to directory and upload to ftp.

But the site gives an error:

```
The directory '/App_GlobalResources/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled.
```

how to publish my site?

**update:**
I Delete the PrecompiledApp.config.

And gives an error

```
Compilation Error 
 Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'UPSRateServiceWebReference.RateService' exists in both 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d6545937\de1fce5a\App_WebReferences.ixuylfle.dll' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d6545937\de1fce5a\assembly\dl3\31691e67\292073b8_400ccd01\App_WebReferences.DLL'

Source Error:


Line 255:
Line 256:        #region PrivateMethods
Line 257:        private RateRequest CreateRateRequest(RateService rate)
Line 258:        {
Line 259:            RateRequest rateRequest = new RateRequest();
```

Comment: Are you uploading to an empty folder?

Comment: Is there already a `/App_GlobalResources` folder in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the PrecompiledApp.config file and re-start your application.

Taken from [here](http://www.ironspeed.com/designer/4.3.0/webhelp/Part_VI/The_directory_XXX_App_GlobalResources_is_not_allowed.htm)

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2013 you should check the option "Precompile During Publishing", I did this the and solved the issue.

[image]

In your case, you could try checking "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable"